# How can I compare rows for multiple columns if they are identical

Tags: python, pandas

I have one pandas DataFrame and I want to check the rows are identical. This shall work for 3 columns out of the dataframe.

```
A B C ...
1 1 1 ...
1 2 3 ...
1 4 4 ...
```

This should bring up a mask with

```
True
False
False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [97]: df.eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(1)
Out[97]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use `nunique`

```
df.nunique(1).eq(1)
Out[1155]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know we have such function. (It was added in Pandas 0.20.0)

Comment: @MaxU to be honestly , I do not think those function are needed..., Your method is faster, I tested it before :-)

Comment: Yes... I really like this one.  And I have a derivative solution.  At least inspired.

Answer (score 3):

Using `diff`

```
df.diff(axis=1).fillna(0).eq(0).all(1)

0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

---

Using `shift`

```
df.eq(df.shift(axis=1)).iloc[:, 1:].all(1)

0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

---

Using `std` (inspired by @Wen)

```
df.std(1).eq(0)

0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

---

Inspired by @MaxU with a healthy amount of obnoxious sprinkled in.

```
(lambda v, j: pd.Series((v == v[:, [0]]).all(1), j))(df.values, df.index)

0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Now with less obnoxious

```
v = df.values
pd.Series((v == v[:, [0]]).all(1), df.index)
```